# Specified cast is not valid when requesting for ID from Database asp.net C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

My problem is that when I want to insert into the database one user it wont let me. I tried to debug it but its not telling me much. Internet didn't help eather, everything that I have written makes sense to me but for some reason I cannot get past this.

```
string query = "Insert Into [dbo].[People] Values (
                @CountryID, 
                @FirstName, 
                @SurName, 
                @Email, 
                @Score);" + "Select Scope_Identity();";
int id;  
try
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryID", natDP.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", nameTb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurName", surnameTB.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", emailTB.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", 1);
            con.Open();
            id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
    emailTB.Text = id.ToString();
}
```

**EDIT**

---

Instead of using the above method to insert parameters I instead created a new method that caters nicely to the above issue.

I have a new controller called `PeopleController` and in this controller I have the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

[Authorize]
public class PeopleController : ApiController //Api controller to resieve ajax requests
{
    // For Retrieving Data
    HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    // Calling DB object
    dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext();

}
```

I then created a new sproc that will be called in a new method, this sproc is then added to my `DbContext` object. The below sql is how it looks.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.sp_People_Insert
(
    @CountryID INT,
    @FirstName VARCHAR(100),
    @SurName VARCHAR(100),
    @Email VARCHAR(100),
    @Score INT
)AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO People(CountryID, FirstName, SurName, Email, Score)
    VALUES (@CountryID, @FirstName, @SurName, @Email, @Score)
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

END
GO
```

**Finally** the method that will be executed. The method will be using ajax to receive the values through the `request` variable. This method is placed in the PeopleController. The ID is then returned as a int.

```
// Insert
public int PostPeople()
{
    int id = db.sp_People_Insert(
        Convert.ToInt32(request["CountyID"]),
        request["FirstName"],
        request["SurName"],
        request["Email"],
        Convert.ToInt32(request["Score"])
        );

    return id;
}
```

I find this a more elegant solution and much more maintainable than having it a input passed to server I instead used ajax.

**Hope it helps who ever stumbles on this very old post, the things you learn in a years time**

Comment: you could replace your `"Select Scope_Identity()"` with the following 
`SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";` also personally I would convert the Insert query into a stored procedure

Comment: @MethodMan Oh my god, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value from your query is not an INT it is a decimal. 
This is the reason of your failed cast.

For example:

```
// Weird but works 
decimal result = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

However using Convert.ToInt32 should also work without changing your query.

```
 id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

In alternative you could apply the suggestion from the comment above or change your query to use OUTPUT INSERTED

```
  @"Insert Into [dbo].[People] OUTPUT INSERTED.PeopleID 
    Values (@CountryID, @FirstName, @SurName, @Email, @Score);"
```

Where PeopleID should be changed to use the real name of your IDENTITY column

Comment: yeah, I used the one from MethodMan, I've been on this problem for days and could not solve it, tried bunch of different methods for inserting. Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0):

you could do this using your string Also what @Steve has suggested would work 
personally I am familiar with both.
I would convert this into a Stored Procedure and save you the headaches of doing Concat Sql Commands

```
string query = "Insert Into [dbo].[People] Values (@CountryID, @FirstName, @SurName, @Email, @Score)SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
```